# Clear firebase database values daily at 5:00 AM using firebase javascript

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a firebase app where new information has to be updated on daily basis. I want to clear firebase database values on daily basis without human intervention.

Is there any way using javascript or any other using which i can perform this step?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

We just released [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), which would get you partially there. It allows you to run your code on Google's servers and respond to events in for example the database.

There isn't yet a way to trigger your code at a specific time though. For that you could use the approach shown in this [sample on deleting unused accounts](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron). It uses a HTTPS function (so a piece of server-side JavaScript code that gets triggered by going to a specific URL), combined with an external web-CRON-emulator service, such as https://www.setcronjob.com/.

Comment: Thanks @Frank Will surely try this